Driving high current to electromagnet with class D amplifier
I have previously designed an amplifier circuit using the OPA541 amplifier for an electromagnet I have developed. This circuit worked fine at low currents (~4 amps) before heating became a huge issue. After some research, I found that class D amplifiers are used in the audio space to drive large voltages/currents with upwards of 95% efficiency. After a bit of research I was able to fine this helpful document that everyone seems to reference: https://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-high-low-side-driver-ir2110-with.html.
I recreated the full bridge drive in LTSpice and I am encountering some issues. Here are all my design specs and circuit diagram with respective output voltages I am seeing in LTSpice:
Electromagnet:

Inductance: 133 uH
Resistance 0.466 ohms
Magnetic field oscillation rate: 0.05 Hz to 5 Hz
Ideal current range: 1-12A

Important components

MOSFETs: IRF540N
MOSFET drivers: IR2113
Signal modulation: LMC555CMX/NOPB + input sine wave from Digilent AD3 into a
LM393BIDGKR

Circuit diagram

Outputs

Signal out of the comparator (blue, S1) and the inverted signal (red, S2)

HO output (green, n002) and LO output (blue, n012)

Gate to source voltage on U1

Gate to source voltage on U3

Current through the electromagnetic coil


Please let me know if there is any blatant error in my circuit that I am missing. Also, I know that a high duty cycle could be affecting this circuit. However, when I input a square wave at 50% duty cycle to both HIN and LIN I still see similar results. Thanks for the help! Let me know if there is anything else I can post to help solve this issue.

Seems your PWM is only running at about 50Hz (I guesstimated 20ms period from your graph). I can't see a bootstrapped driver like the IR2113 working very well at such a low frequency, particularly with only a 47uF cap trying to supply the 1k resistors you have on your NMOS gates.

As a side question, do you need a full bridge just to drive an electro-magnet?  I would think you could do this with just a half-bridge.  The high side feeds it current and the low side is the synchronous rectifier.

@brhans, thank you for the response! I increased the PWM frequency to 14 kHz based on the saw tooth waveform in the LMC555 datasheet. I also tried a variety of different bootstrap capacitor values and resistor values. However, none of these changes seem to be driving the high side output correctly. I am unsure what is wrong with my circuit. When I look online most class D amplifiers are built the same way. Any further suggestions?

@Aaron I was attempting the full bridge in order to create a positive magnetic field and then a negative magnetic field. I couldn't seem to find much on the current waveforms out of these circuits showing a positive and negative current. So I assumed that the half bridge would only allow positive current flow. I could be very wrong with this as this is my first time using circuits with MOSFETs and drivers. I hope it could work as a half bridge cause that would mean less components!

If you want to change the polarity of the magnetic field, then yes, you'll need a full bridge as you have.

C5,C11 seem pretty large.  They only need to be ~10-20x larger than the input capacitance of the FET.  This usually means about 1uF-2uF.  If it's too large, then it'll take too long to charge and you won't get a high voltage to drive the high side.
